# Python: how to change cell num type using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I am using python to convert my **.csv file to xlsx files**, file conversion happens successfully. At the same time I would like to change the cell num type also, like where ever there are float type xx.xxxx, that will be reduced to .xx (2 decimals) values.

input test.csv sheet, seperated by ","

```
Name        Date        Total request   sas rate
rasta777    16062017    387865          89.3456
rasta777    16062017    291293          67.675
rasta777    16062017    256418          100
rasta777    16062017    251558          98.98
```

I have already tried the below python script using `xlsxwriter`, but getting an error.

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', 'hourly.csv')):
workbook = Workbook(csvfile + '.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
format = workbook.add_format()
format.set_bold()
format.set_font_color('blue')
format.set_num_format('0x02')
format1 = workbook.add_format({'font_color': 'blue'})
with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(r, c, col)
            worksheet.set_row(0, 20, format)
            worksheet.set_column('A:P', format)
workbook.close()
```

getting error that

> "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Format' and 'int'"

My second problem is generated output (getting output if I remove  `worksheet.set_column('A:P', format)`) gives cell type as text, whereas my data is all of numerical values except headers.

Comment: The first issue is probably caused by adding a hex value as a string. Try 0x2 instead or just 2.

Comment: The second issue is due to the fact that the csv module will read all data in as strings even if they look like numbers. You can workaround this by using the `strings_to_numbers` constructor option in XlsxWriter: .http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#constructor

Comment: after adding strings_to_numbers, both the issues resolved now. may i know how to apply float (.xx format) for only particular column??? as per the my table, 4th column is having float values.   worksheet.set_column('A:P', 18, format1) applies format1 parameters to all columns. i have already defined a format2, which have 0x2 num type, how to add this to worksheet.set line?

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked XlsxWriter's `worksheet` did not support changing the cell type after the value was written. When you want to write a value of specific type, you have to write it using a method specific to a type, like so:

```
worksheet.write_datetime(idx, fld_idx, fld, date_format)
```

You also have to specify format *while writing* and I don't think it's possible to change the format after the fact.

Generally, I've learned by experience with XlsxWriter that it's better to prepare everything you need before writing and then write the cell once with all the correct values. So e.g. I use the `date_format` predefined the usual way while writing the `datetime` to the cell. That works.

Read up on type-specific methods here: http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html, in particular:

```
write_string()
write_number()
write_blank()
write_formula()
write_datetime()
write_boolean()
write_url()
```